# How to determine if a view is visible in a ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I want to be able to tell if a view is visible in my listview, which is populated by a custom CursorAdapter. How can I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can check whether a given position is visible, using `getFirstVisiblePosition()` and `getChildCount()`.

Comment: he asked about views . what you gave him are methods that return integers . how will it be possible to know which of the views that were given to the listview in the past are currently shown in the listview and which aren't? i think that you would need to have to check that for the given view , get the position that it is currently showing , and then use the methods you've described to check that it's inside this range of values.

Comment: And do you have an example of that?