# editText pop-up error displayed above an image instead to be displayed below

Tags: android

I have the following android code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

EditText username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
username.setError("test eeerrr ");
    }
}
```

and This is the **activity_main.xml** file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" 
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" 
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
 <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1">
  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">
     <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:text="Button" />

     <EditText android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:ems="10">
        <requestFocus />
     </EditText>
     <Button android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:text="Button" />
     <Button android:id="@+id/button3" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:text="Button" />
     <Button android:id="@+id/button4" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:text="Button" />
     <Button android:id="@+id/button5" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:text="Button" />
     <Button android:id="@+id/button6" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:text="Button" />
     <Button android:id="@+id/button7" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:text="Button" />
     <Button android:id="@+id/button8" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:text="Button" />
     <Button android:id="@+id/button9" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:text="Button" />
     <Button android:id="@+id/button10" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:text="Button" />
     <Button android:id="@+id/button11" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:text="Button" />
     <Button android:id="@+id/button12" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:text="Button" />
     <Button android:id="@+id/button13" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:text="Button" />
     <Button android:id="@+id/button14" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:text="Button" />
  </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

When I scroll up, the error pop up from the edit text is displayed above the image: imageView1. I want that the pop up error to be displayed below the TestLogin image.[image: Error displayed without scroll]
  [image: Error displayed after scroll]